# Redirect JSP from JSP - error "The requested resource is not available."

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a social networking site and I have the following problem. In `profile.jsp` I have a form where the user can upload a photo. This form has an action to `FileUploadHandler` servlet which uploads the photo and then sends redirect to `uploadfileController.jsp` like this:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher;
requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/uploadfileController.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In `uploadfileController.jsp` I insert this post into my MySQL database and I send redirect to `profile.jsp`.

```
response.sendRedirect("/profile.jsp");
```

But then I get this error message:

> HTTP Status 404 - /profile.jsp
>
> type Status report
>
> message /profile.jsp
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

However, when I go again to `profile.jsp` the post is created! Any ideas?

Comment: How does full URL to your `profile.jsp` looks like? Is it something like `http://server/webAppName/profile.jsp`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response is relative to servlet context then prepend context path to the URL.

```
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/profile.jsp");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sendRedirect` with relative address. For instance if servlets URL is

> **http://www.serwer.com/yourwebapp/foo/**servlet

and you will use `sendRedirect("bar/other")` you will be redirected to different resource in same context

> **http://www.serwer.com/yourwebapp/foo/**bar/other

BUT if you add `/` at start of `sendRedirect` then `/` will represent main directory of your server,

```
http://www.serwer.com/
                     ^this one
```

so `sendRedirect("/bar/other")` will redirect you to

> **http://www.serwer.com/**bar/other

so as you see `yourwebapp` and `foo` was removed from URL.

In your case it seems that problem is lack of `yourwebapp`. You can solve it in many ways. For instance you can:

- remove `/` from start of redirection location to make it relative to current URL
- add application name after `/` like `sendRedirect("/yourAppName/profile.jsp")` (you can dynamically get `/yourAppName` by using `request.getContextPath()` as [mentioned by Roman C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009070/1393766) +1 for his info)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused and you helped a lot!! :)

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou You are welcome. Losing application name while creating redirection is one of standard problems we face in web development :)

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou if he helped a lot, you should upvote his answer ;)