# How to set HTTP header in JSP or on index.jsp?

Tags: java, html, http, struts, servlet-filters

How to set HTTP header in `index.jsp`?

I have done servlet filter coding to set `HttpHeader` whenever any request comes like `*.do`.

But `index.java` is initial JSP page will not get call when `*.do` action hit.

So I want set below header initially:

```
response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

Answer (score 0):

Index page `index.jsp` is not managed by Struts. However, Struts can return it as a view.

When request is coming to index page `index.jsp` not by Struts then you can't set headers to the response via a filter. You should use index page only to redirect to the action. Then you can set headers using the filter.

You can use `response` object to redirect to the action similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009070/573032) answer.

Comment: So it is not possible or it has no use to setHeader in index.jsp ?            Cause whiteHite security guys create Vulnerability in our index page saying that  response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");  is not present at first Login page

Comment: You can set headers in the action, not in jsp.

Comment: Yes we have to set in action. so I have set the same in my filter and its gets set after my login page cause login.do action gets hit. But it does not get visible on our first page that our login webpage. they are checking in browser >f12 > developer tools>network > response headers  whether x-margin is present or not

Comment: To make it visible you should redirect request to the action with `response.sendRedirect()`  or using http refresh. Then the action will return jsp as a result.